# Leaving .net SqlConnection open indefinitely vs a using block

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclient

I have a deep dive question. I want to understand why a `SqlConnection` is getting closed and how to detect whether connection pooling is actually taking place.

I have two different versions of a class which abstract talking to a database and returning a `DataTable`. What I am providing is an example of the problem/question.

Version 1 opens a `SqlConnection` upon instantiation and leaves it open. This is a single threaded process which handles incoming messages and writes the results to the database as fast as possible. That is the idea behind leaving `SqlConnection` perpetually open:

```
public class SpecialDbClientVersion1 : IDisposable
{
    string connStr;
    SqlConnection dbConn;

    public SpecialDbClientVersion1(string connStr)
    {
        this.connStr = connStr;
        this.dbConn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

        try
        {
            dbConn.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"An exception occurred while trying to connect to {dbConn.Database}", ex);
        }
    }

    public DataTable QuerySqlReturnResultAsDataTable(string sql, int commandTimeout = 30)
    {
        try
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dbConn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I test this, everything goes fine and there is incredibly high throughput. Eventually though the `SqlConnection` gets closed for some reason. An error gets thrown and the party is over.

**Question 1**: can someone explain what would cause this connection to go into a `Closed` state without me calling the `Close()` method?

Now version 2 performs all the work in a `using` block. Per the internet, the runtime should magically use connection pooling under the hood. This is the best practice for working with `SqlConnection` objects per Microsoft. With connection pooling there should not be much of a performance hit.

```
public class SpecialDbClientVersion2
{
    string connStr;
    SqlConnection dbConn;

    public SpecialDbClientVersion2(string connStr)
    {
        this.connStr = connStr;
    }

    public DataTable QuerySqlReturnResultAsDataTable(string sql, int commandTimeout = 30)
    {
        using(var dbConn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
                var dt = new DataTable();
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question 2:** how can I tell if connection pooling is actually being used? This writing the database needs to be as fast as possible and I am concerned that version 2 will have to re-establish a connection to the database every time. This would destroy performance. How can I measure whether connection pooling is occurring and whether it is impacting the throughput of the service?

I have been looking for Deep Dive resources on this subject but most of what I find is just "Use a SqlConnection in a `using` block and everything will be fine." I am looking for a deeper explanation than that. I really want to understand the guts of what is occurring here so that I hunt the correct performance issue. Thank you for whatever insight you can offer.

Comment: You are forgetting that the communications is over ethernet and often server will shutdown connections when traffic exceeds a certain limit or the channel is idle.  I would start by looking at the database log files to see why the connection was closed.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. That is the kind of information I am looking for.

Comment: everything you need to know about connection pooling is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: I have read that documentation in great detail. It did not address how to monitor whether the expected behavior was actually occurring. I appreciate the link but it is part of why I asked this question. I am needing insight one layer deeper than what this provides. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the connection may be being closed on the server side or by a idle timeout, check the server side logs for details.

For your 2nd part of your question, there are performance counters that [tracks connection pool information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters). This can be viewed via code (see linked page for an example) setting the process id of your running program and displaying the value of things like `NumberOfPooledConnections` and `NumberOfNonPooledConnections` to see if the connection pool is actually being used by the process.

By turning on the [off by default counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters#ActivatingOffByDefault) you could also monitor `NumberOfFreeConnections` which would tell you if there is a free open connection for your program to pick up and use to get that immediate response without the overhead of opening a connection you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 could be answered by the fact there is an idle timeout associated with the pool.

Question 2: Connection pooling is set to true by default, so if you aren't explicitly turning it off in the connection string, you can assume you're using it.  I don't think there's a way to determine how many connections are left in the pool.  If you're using EXACTLY the same connection string each time, then you can safely assume they are in the same pool.

Read this document to get a more in depth grasp of connection pooling.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

You would have to monitor the connections at the SQL Server level.

```
SELECT 
DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
loginame as LoginName
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE bid > 0
GROUP BY dbid, loginame;
```

Comment: I am familiar with this documentation. What I am looking for is how to monitor Connection Pooling to ensure it is behaving as I believe it should.

Comment: You can monitor the connection pool activity on the server with Trace or XEvents.  The Audit Login Event fires for both new connections and the re-use of a pooled connection, with a different Event Subtype: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-login-event-class?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft awesome! This is what I am needing!